# Crystal Report Creation in VS express step by step

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'ReportDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    D:\SoftwareiLogicc#\customer\customer\FrmReportViewer.cs    22  9   customer
this error occure during the report load in c#

```
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();                 
reportdocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + 
@"D:\\SoftwareiLogicc#\Report\MyFirstCrystalReport.rpt");
reportdocument.SetDataSource((DataTable)dt);
reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
reportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have using

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

namespace for remove given error

Answer (score 0):

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
```

Put these in your class to make an instance of `ReportDocument`.